# Is there a `unload` item for Createjs' preloadjs/soundjs

Tags: createjs, soundjs, preloadjs

Once you've loaded a mp3 into a sound object via createjs, how dow you destroy & clear it from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are static methods for this:

1. `removeSound`: Remove stored references to sounds by source
2. `removeSounds`: Remove multiple sound src's
3. `removeAllSounds`: Wipe references to sounds

**Examples**

```
 createjs.Sound.removeSound("myID");
 createjs.Sound.removeSound("myAudioBasePath/mySound.ogg");
 createjs.Sound.removeSound("myPath/myOtherSound.mp3", "myBasePath/");
 createjs.Sound.removeSound({mp3:"musicNoExtension", ogg:"music.ogg"}, "myBasePath/");
```

Check out [the docs](http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/Sound.html#method_removeSound) for more info.

This is not a super common use-case, so if you run into issue, please feel free to open an issue on [GitHub](http://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues)

Comment: ooo, Nice! Thanks Lanny, I'll give this a shot.